# Trouble Reading and Formatting Date

Tags: swiftui, ios14, xcode12

I'm attempting to read some data from CoreData into a standard list and have trouble reading and formatting the date. I appear to be way off in the weeds! I have the error "Value of type 'Date?' has no member 'getFormattedDate'" where I'm trying to display the date and the error "Cannot convert value of type 'listView' to expected argument type 'Date'" at the last line of the getFormattedDate function.

```
struct listView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    let categories = ["AAA", "BBB","CCC","DDD"]
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: []
    ) var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(currTrans, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack {
                    let date = item.entryDT
                    Text(date.getFormattedDate())
                      
                    // display category
                    if item.entryCat != nil {
                        Text("Category: \(categories[Int(item.entryCat)])")
                    } else {
                        Text("")
                    
                    // display description
                    if item.entryDsc != nil {
                        Text("\(item.entryDsc!)")
                    } else {
                        Text("")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        func getFormattedDate() -> String {
            let dateformat = DateFormatter()
            dateformat.dateFormat = "d MMM HH:mm"
            return dateformat.string(from: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@objc(Transaction)
public class Transaction: NSManagedObject {
    static let categoryStringsByCategoryID = ["AAA", "BBB","CCC","DDD"]
    func categoryString() -> String{
         return Transaction.categoryStringsByCategoryID[self.categoryID]
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var transactions: FetchedResults<Transaction>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(transactions) { transaction in
                VStack {
                    Text("\(transaction.timestamp!, formatter: transactionFormatter)")
                    // display category
                    
                    Text("Category: \(transaction.categoryString)")
                    
                    // display description
                    Text("\(transaction.entryDescription ?? "")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private let transactionFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```